# Test uniform convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(n+x)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

The question says :

Test the uniform convergence and term-by-term integration of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(n+x)^2}$

My response:

Had this been on a bounded set, series would have been uniformly convergent and hence by property, would have term-by-term integrable

But what about its uniform convergence for $\forall x \geq 0$

Comment: Th e series is not even defined on the whole of $\mathbb R$. You have to exclude the point $-1,-2,...$ from the domain of definition.

Comment: Agreed, lets discuss the for $x \geq 0$

Comment: For $x$ not a negative integer, the partial sums are given by
$$
S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac x{(k+x)^2} = x (\psi ^{(1)}(x+1)-\psi ^{(1)}(n+x+1)),
$$
where $\psi^{(1)}(z) = \frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}$ denotes the PolyGamma function. The limit as $n\to\infty$ is
$$
x \psi ^{(1)}(x+1).
$$
This is likely going to be difficult to solve by hand.

Comment: Yes, this is something new for me. I will look more into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't converge uniformly.  First off, it's not defined on the negative integers, but even if you exclude them, what you're trying to prove is that for every strictly positive $\epsilon$ there is an $N$ such that for every $x$ (as opposed to pointwise "for every $x$ there is an $N$") the remainder of the series beginning at $N$ is less than $\epsilon$.  Therefore, to show that it doesn't converge uniformly, it suffices to show that for every $N$ there exists an $x$ such that the remainder of the series beginning at $N$ is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$.  The integral test will tell you that, for positive $x$, the series beginning at $N$ is always greater than $\frac{x}{N+x}$, and you simply need to choose $x>2N$.

Comment: Perfect! But then what will you say about 2nd part which is term-by-term integrable or not ?

Comment: Monotone convergence theorem?  At least for positive $x$.

Comment: Kindly elaborate a little.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\sup_{x\in [0,\infty)} \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{x}{(k+x)^2} \geqslant \sup_{x\in [0,\infty)} n \frac{x}{(2n+x)^2} \geqslant n \frac{n}{(3n)^2} = \frac{1}{9}$$

and the left-hand side does not converge to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Hence, the Cauchy criterion is violated and the series is not uniformly convergent on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: what can be said about the possibility of term-by-term integration ?

Comment: @Sarkar: As convergence is uniform on intervals $[a,b]$ where $0\leqslant a<b$ the series converges to a function that is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and termwise integration holds. You pointed this out yourself. This holds as well on closed intervals of the negative real line that avoid negative integers as well. The uniform convergence follows from the Weierstrass test. I just answered your question regarding uniform convergence for all $x\geqslant 0$. What else are you concerned about? The improper or Lebesgue integral over $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: For your latest question after this one, the series is in fact uniformly convergent.

Comment: Why don't you prove it there itself. For the upvoting part, my sincere apologies. I will keep that in mind

Comment: @Sarkar:  Thank you.

Comment: since uniform convergence is only sufficient condition for term-by-term integration to hold, i was wondering if this series can be integrated term-by-term for $\forall x \geq 0$

Answer (score 0):

As @Math1000 commented, the exact solution for the infinite summation is 
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(n+x)^2}=x\, \psi ^{(1)}(x+1)$$

If you are not requiring too much accuracy, you could have a very decent approximation building around $x=0$ the $[3,3]$ Padé approximant. This would give
$$S\sim \frac{x\left(\frac{\pi^2}6 +a x+b x^2\right)} {1+c x+d x^2+e x^3}$$ The exact formulae for $(a,b,c,d,e)$ are really messy but, numerically, they are
$$a=2.20248\quad b=0.824897 \quad c=2.80048\quad d=2.62052 \quad e=0.823552$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
x & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 0.644942 & 0.644934 \\
 2 & 0.789937 & 0.789868 \\
 3 & 0.851641 & 0.851469 \\
 4 & 0.885576 & 0.885292 \\
 5 & 0.907006 & 0.906615 \\
 6 & 0.921758 & 0.921271 \\
 7 & 0.932532 & 0.931959 \\
 8 & 0.940744 & 0.940096 \\
 9 & 0.947211 & 0.946497 \\
 10 & 0.952436 & 0.951663
\end{array}
\right)$$